# Why does a for loop stops unexpectedly during an iteration of a list while the list gets deleted?

Tags: python, buffer-overflow

The problem lies in the last for loop block. It should pop the expo list to complete vanishing but it stops at length 32. I cannot imagine why.

I tried the list.pop method and also as shown the del operator. Both raise the same error.

```
def generator(): # generator which generates like 2,4,8,16 -> 2 to the power of x
    list = range(1,65)
    for i in list:
        yield 2**i

mygen = generator() # generator object

expo = [] # empty list for the exponential values

for i in mygen: # for loop to put the values of the genertor in list form
    expo.append(i)
    print(expo)

for i in expo: # attempt to delete the last element, but stops at list with length 32
    del expo[-1]
    print(expo)
```

I expected that the list would get deleted as it was build stepwise. It should become [] but becomes len(expo)=32 .

So why does it stop ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting the list you are iterating on, which ends up deleting only half the list, and then the iteration stops on 32 elements (since the length of the `expo` list is `64`, half of it is `32`

You have two options:

- Iterate on the copy of the list and delete the actual list .

```
#Iterating on copy of expo
for i in expo[:]:
    del expo[-1]
    print(expo)
```

- Use `list.clear` to clear the list in one step instead of the for loop

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

> list.clear()
>   Remove all items from the list. Equivalent to del a[:].

```
expo.clear()
print(expo)
#[]
```

Comment: Does expo[:] creates the copy?

Comment: Yes, it does, it's called slicing in python, although you won't need that approach, you can just clear the list in one step @MaxRandom as per my second option :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I am very thankful for your time and help!

Comment: Hi @MaxRandom I saw you accepted and then unaccepted my answer, could you please let me know if something was missing in the answer. and I can fix it :)

Comment: accepted your solution

Answer (score 2):

You're constantly deleting the last element of the list `expo[-1]`
So when you've cleared ~half your list (32/64 elements), there's simply no more values to iterate over and the iteration stops.

As a rule of thumb, it's generally a bad idea to manipulate a list mid-iteration as this kind of unexpected behavior might happen.